# Drupal: Execute custom PHP code not anymore available

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

In my Drupal rules settings I don't have "Execute custom PHP code" option anymore.

Do you know if there is an option to remove it ? I'm logged in as administrator user.

thanks

Comment: In what context do you miss it? Blocks? Editing nodes?

Comment: hey man, just see my comment on your prev.question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under /admin/build/modules make sure the core PHP Filter module is enabled.